# fit terminal columns to output width

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I have noticed that output of mysql selects/commands are nicely formatted, exceeding default terminal columns set (80), I only have to resize terminal window to see all columns in 1 row. How can it be configured ?
I am using HERE document with comments longer than 80 characters, which are then passed to SSH session (I don't mind see them later in output),
but rather than expand to row, characters on 81. position and later continue to overwrite my login name at prompt like so :

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -A -tt -l user1 192.168.1.10 <<ABC
#-----------------------------------------------------
#comments are very useful for explaining what does your code actually do. And sometimes they can be very long.
#-----------------------------------------------------
some_command
exit
ABC
```

and here's my output:

```
[user@server ~]$ #-----------------------------------------------------
 actually do. And sometimes they can be very long.explaining what does your code
[user@server ~]$ #-----------------------------------------------------
```

***EDIT***

expected result:

```
[user@server ~]$ #-----------------------------------------------------
[user@server ~]$ # comments are very useful for explaining what does your code actually do. And sometimes they can be very long. Even over 80 characters.
[user@server ~]$ #-----------------------------------------------------
```

any idea how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing a `tty` allocation (`ssh -tt`) but I bet that the terminal's dimensions are not set properly (no dimension maybe). Assuming you really need that `-tt` option, you can start your script with a `stty` line that sets the terminal's dimensions:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -A -tt -l user1 192.168.1.10 <<ABC
stty $(stty size | sed 's/ / cols /;s/^/rows /')
#-----------------------------------------------------
#comments are very useful for explaining what does your code actually do. And sometimes they can be very long.
#-----------------------------------------------------
some_command
exit
ABC
```

Here, we build an `stty` command using the actual size of your terminal. If your current terminal is 80x25, `stty size` will yield `25 80` and, after substitution, the resulting command will be `stty rows 25 cols 80`.

Comment: thanks, that fixed it. I'd like to add that it has something to do with screen resolution too, as I have my 1920x1080 monitor flipped clockwise (portrait), if turned back to normal position, terminal output works correctly. Your solution works. Also, I noticed that mysql output is nicely formatted always, maybe they are using similar approach in their source code